# No such element or plugin 'kvssink'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Getting the error "No such element or plugin 'kvssink'" after the build completes as instructed in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.